# Retrieving Birth DATE data from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve a date data from mysql DB. But it returns N/A even though its not null. But when I comment out the 2nd If(statement) it returns January 01, 1970 but the actual data is June 6, 1952. BusDateHired and DateOfBirth
are in the same table. The membership date is perfectly fine, it retrieve the actual data from database.

```
# GET MEMBERS INFO.
$meminfo_sql = sqlCLIENTINFO($clientid, $br_code);
$meminfo_query = mysql_query($meminfo_sql) or die("ERROR GETTING MEMBER'S DATA".mysql_error());
$meminfo_data = mysql_fetch_array($meminfo_query);


# SET variables for members data.
$fullname = $meminfo_data['LName'].", ".$meminfo_data['FName']." ".$meminfo_data['MName'];
$temp_dateHired= explode("-", $meminfo_data['BusDateHired']);
$temp_dateopened = explode("-", $meminfo_data['DateOpened']);
$temp_birthDate= explode("-", $meminfo_data['DateOfBirth']);

# Date of Birth
$meminfo_birthDate= "";
    if($meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'] != "No Data" || $meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'] != null || !is_null($meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'])){
$meminfo_birthDate = date("F d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$temp_birthDate[1],$temp_birthDate[2],$temp_birthDate[0])); # date format January 01, 2013
}
#end of Date of Birth

# Date of hired..
$meminfo_dateHired= "";
if($meminfo_data['BusDateHired'] != "No Data"){
    $meminfo_dateHired = date("F d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$temp_dateHired[1],$temp_dateHired[2],$temp_dateHired[0])); # date-format January 01, 2013
}
if (is_null($meminfo_data['BusDateHired'])) {
   $meminfo_dateHired = 'N/A';
}
# end of Date of hired
```

Comment: your 2nd if is strange. You should put in in an else if instead, or test for `$meminfo_birthDate` value instead (`!== ""` ?)

Comment: please attach response of `$temp_birthDate` array.

Comment: show your whole code! you are asking a question about the result of a mysql and don't even include your mysql code?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. could you give me an example how should I do it? if its ok guys.. By the way im using the same code in retrieving my membership date, and its fine it returns the actual data.. I dont know why, why its not working in Birthdate.

Comment: Like @low_rents said, provide more details and code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$meminfo_birthDate= "";
if($meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'] != "No Data" || $meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'] != null || !is_null($meminfo_data['DateOfBirth'])){
  $meminfo_birthDate = date("F d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$temp_birthDate[1],$temp_birthDate[2],$temp_birthDate[0])); # date format January 01, 2013
}
```

I have tried your code online with demo date its working fine.

```
echo date("F d, Y",mktime(0,0,0,02,03,2015));
```

Output:

```
February 03, 2015
```

**Online Demo[Click Here](https://eval.in/564143)**

Comment: So just you need to check your `$temp_birthDate` and check its order and i think its creating issue so its giving you default date `January 01, 1970` as output.